# Problem With Twitter Widget Link Font Size

Tags: css, twitter

[On this site](http://www.2touchrulz.com/) the Twitter widget in the sidebar appears to be taking instructions from the sidebar's CSS. The links are obviously way too big. Is there a way to isolate it from the sidebar's CSS while keeping it in the sidebar?

Thank you - Tara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use **#sidebar a** to assign styles to your links. A tags in the sidebar are picking up your style. Give your links their own class and change the font size that way.

CSS: `a.mylinks {font-size: 16px;}`

And code:`<a class='mylinks' href='whatever.htm'>Link</a>`

**Edit**
Change your CSS selector from `#sidebar a` to `#sidebar li a` as show in my comment below.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much control over that - they're called by php... Is there a way I could put divs around the twitter widget to 'protect' it from the sidebar css? Thanks @yeodave

Comment: Yep, change the CSS file, line 382 that says **#sidebar a {** to say **#sidebar li a {** therefore it will only affect "A" tags within lists (like yours) and leave the widget's "A" tags alone.